# Check if a section is defined in a view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-blade

Using Laravel, how can I modify my layout depending on whether a specific section is defined in a view?

I know I can have some default text display if the section does not exist, but imagine the following scenario:

```
<div class="row">  
     <div class="col-sm-9"> 
         @yield('content')
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
         @section('sidebar')
         @show
     </div>
</div>
```

So if my view defines the @section 'sidebar', this works great.  But if the view doesn't define a sidebar, I don't want my main content column to be col-sm-9, I want it to be col-sm-12.  I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
@if(@section('sidebar'))
    <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-sm-9"> 
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            @section('sidebar')
            @show
        </div>
    </div>
@else
    <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-sm-12"> 
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

However that doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone suggest an alternative?

thanks!

Comment: You are trying to solve CSS problems with laravel-blade. This is wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this to tell if a section is defined or not :

```
@if (!empty($__env->yieldContent('sidebar')))
   //It is defined
@endif
```

`$__env->yieldContent()` returns the content of the specified section, or an empty string if it is not defined or empty.

**Edit**

Prior to PHP 5.5 `empty()`  will not work on the result of a function directly, so you can use `trim()` instead, like so :

```
@if (trim($__env->yieldContent('sidebar')))
   //It is defined
@endif
```

Comment: When I try this I get the error "Error: Can't use method return value in write context"

Answer (score 42):

Laravel 5.2 added a `@hasSection` directive that does exactly what you're asking.
It's not mentioned in 5.3 or 5.4 docs for some reason.

```
@hasSection('title')
    <title>@yield('title') - {{ config('app.name') }}</title>
@else
    <title>{{ config('app.name') }}</title>
@endif
```